# Compiling gcc-c++ 4.9.2 -std=c++14 in CLion JetBrains IDE [solved]

Tags: windows, gcc, c++

I was trying to compile a cpp program using option -std=c++14 in CLion. But I got an error saying
**g++ error: Unrecognized command line -std=c++14**

It's working fine using **-std=c+11**.

My cmakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(untitled)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(untitled ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

I'm using MingW-w64 gcc-x86_64-4.9.2-posix.

**Edit: It has been solved by removing the path for msys that includes sh.exe.

C:\msys\usr\bin\sh.exe**

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer)